# Confusion about the implementation of thresholding operation

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I was reading this [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/sustik/papers/invcov.pdf). I didn't get the application of thresholding operator here

[image]

I didn't get how the -c part came in the solution

$\mu = -c + S(c-b/a, \lambda/a)$

Comment: @all. I have solved it. Not a problem anymore